# Schatten $p$-ideals for Hilbert operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

As I was solving exercise E.3.4.2. in Gert Pedersen's *Analysis Now*, I got two questions.

**1.** Let $1 \leq p < \infty$. Pedersen defines Schatten $p$-ideals $\mathcal{B}^p (\mathcal{H})$ as the set of compact operators $T \in \mathcal{B}_0 (\mathcal{H})$ such that $|T|^p$ is trace class. He then defines the norm on the Schatten ideals:
$$\|T\|_p = (\mathrm{tr} (|T|^p))^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$ The exercise asks us to prove that the Schatten ideals are in fact ideals and the $p$-norm really is a norm. His hint for proving the additivity (and the triangle inequality) is essentially to consider $S, T$ and then take the polar decompositions
$$S = U |S|,\quad T = V|T|,\quad S + T = W|S + T|.$$
Then we are supposed to take any finite projection $Q$ that commutes with $|A + B|$ to get
$$\mathrm{tr} (|S + T|^p Q) \leq \mathrm{tr} (|S||S + T|^{p - 1} Q) + \mathrm{tr} (|T||S + T|^{p - 1} Q).$$
Then we are supposed to use the inequality
$$\mathrm{tr} (|AB|) \leq (\mathrm{tr} (S^p))^{\frac{1}{p}} (\mathrm{tr} (S^q))^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
for positive $A, B \in \mathcal{B}^p (\mathcal{H})$ and $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$. According to the author, we can use this inequality to get the bound
$$\mathrm{tr} (|S||S + T|^{p - 1} Q) \leq \|S\|_p \| |S + T| Q \|_p ^{p - 1}$$
and similarly
$$\mathrm{tr} (|T||S + T|^{p - 1} Q) \leq \|T\|_p \| |S + T| Q \|_p ^{p - 1}.$$
It is this last step that I'm having trouble with: **why is $\mathrm{tr} (|S||S + T|^{p - 1} Q) = \mathrm{tr} (\left||S||S + T|^{p - 1} Q\right|)$?**

**2.** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) claims that if we take all bounded (not necessarily compact) operators $S \in \mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H})$ such that $|S|^p$
is trace class, then this is a Banach space with the above norm. Bizarrely enough, I couldn't find one reference on the internet that proved this for a general non-separable Hilbert space.
Is there perhaps an elementary argument that generalized Pedersen's proof to non-compact operators?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $|S|^p$ is trace class, then $S$ is compact as remarked on the same wikipedia page you have linked to.

Comment: I didn't really understand that argument. Sure, if $|S|^p$ is trace-class, then it has either a finite spectrum or a countable one that has a limit point at 0, so the same must be true for $|S|$ by countinuous functional calculus. I don't immediately see how that implies compactness of $|S|$.

Comment: Concerning your first question $|trA|\le tr|A|.$

Comment: Your question in the comment:: if $tr|S|<\infty$ then $|S|$ can be approximated by finite dimensional operators.

Comment: @the_dude if $|S|$ is trace class and you know that it has countable spectrum with only accumulation point 0, then $|S|$ is the limit in operator norm of finite range operators (use the measurable functional calculus).

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Regarding your last comment, could you elaborate on how did you derive that $\mathrm{tr} |S| < \infty$?

Comment: Sorry, I  meant $tr|S|^p<\infty.$ One can use a simple inequality $\|S\|^p\le tr|S|^p<\infty$ to perform approximation of $|S|$ by finite rank operators.